# Difference between admin task vs job db2

Tags: database, db2

What is the difference between Admin task and job in db2? I scheduled am admin task to delete rows of data but it is not working. I am deleting through procedure delete_procedure. Is it the right syntax?

```
call SYSPROC.ADMIN_TASK_ADD ( 'task_delete', 
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL,
                                  '50 3 * * *',
                                  'db_2',
                                  'delete_procedure',
                                  'values(''delete logs'') ',
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL )
```

Answer (score 0):

In the standard CRON format, all five fields are mandatory. Therefor the schedule parameter should contain:

'50 3 * * *'

Other than that your syntax looks correct, but any other errors would be hard to diagnose without the code for the procedure you're calling, to make sure that the parameters you're passing are correct.

Comment: There may be other reasons it's not working besides syntax. When you say it is not working, does that mean never attempting to run, or produces an error? Could you tell us what shows in the ADMIN_TASK_STATUS view for SQLCODE, SQLSTATE, SQLERRMC and RC for this task?